# Exportar listado de las extensiones de VSC instaladas

Tags: vscode

Tengo la versión 1.86.2 en Ubuntu.

He estado mirando las opciones disponibles en la sección de extensiones (clic en los 3 puntos arriba a la dcha.) y no encuentro nada.
Tampoco encontré una extensión.

Comment: No se si hay una opción para eso, sería bueno saberlo. Lo que siempre hago es una captura de pantalla (o varias) ‍️

Comment: Tal vez esto es lo que buscas: [How can you export the Visual Studio Code extension list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-the-visual-studio-code-extension-list)

Answer (score 1):

Abres la terminal y ejecutas:

```
code --list-extensions > extensions.txt
```

Se crea un archivo de tipo texto con la lista de dichas extensiones, en el directorio donde se guardan la extensiones del editor: `~/.vscode/extensions`.

Para ver el listado:

```
code --list-extensions
```

Más sobre el comando: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_command-line-extension-management

Comment: Me crea un fichero "extensions.txt" vació.

Comment: Ese es el comando, por favor revisa este link de la documentación de Vscode busca el apartado "Command line extension management" aquí el link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace

Comment: Ejecuta el mismo comando pero ahora directo desde el mismo directorio en Linux es "cd ~/.vscode/extensions", si quieres primero lo lista "code --list-extensions" antes de colocarlo en el archivo de texto.

Comment: si aparecen los ficheros en el directorio `~/.vscode/extensions` de todos modos para lo que busco y con los metadatos que incorporan mejor solo listarlas. Edita tu respuesta y añade la información adicional de tus comentarios para que pueda ser valorada.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma de [exportar el perfil del editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75614465/3919660), incluidas las extensiones, o sólo las extensiones, lo que permitiría posteriormente cargar los datos en otra instalación del editor (en la versión actual).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comando: `Profiles: Export Profile`

Nos permire guardar el json generado en local o en los *[gists de Github](https://docs.github.com/es/get-started/writing-on-github/editing-and-sharing-content-with-gists/creating-gists)*.

Para importar `Profiles: Import Profile`.

***NOTA**: hay una serie de "perfiles predefinidos" que podemos cargar cuando se va a trabajar con un lenguaje o *stack* concreto, ofrece varios: Python, Angular, Java, ... **esto reemplazara a la configuración y extensiones que tengamos actualmente***.

Para exportar / importar o gestionar el perfil en uso, podemos abrir el menu de configuración (rueda dentada abajo a la izquierda) y seleccionar "Profiles".